# Which one is better in performance in accessing length of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have an array. I would like do some operation based on the presence of items in the array.

Which approach is better in performance using javascript.

```
if (!myArr.length) {
   //do something.
}
```

**OR**

```
if (myArr.length === 0) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Worry about it **if** you see a performance problem you've tracked down to that bit of code. (E.g.: Don't worry about it.)

Comment: Which approach is preferred?

Comment: ***Neither***, it's totally up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which approach is better in performance using javascript

The answer to this question for JavaScript code is almost always:

1. It depends on the engine, and
2. If it matters, [test it](http://jsperf.com) on the engines you need to support. [Here's a test you can use](http://jsperf.com/checking-array-has-entries).

I very much doubt that it matters, though, this is unlikely to be a performance bottleneck in your code.